# Getting Decoded Version of a Unicode String?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, unicode

I write a variable into my HTML element as like that:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = '<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>';
```

However it is written as like that:

```
TECHNO A.&#x15E;.
```

which should be:

```
TECHNO A.Ş.
```

How can I manually get decoded version of that Unicode string with Javascript?

**PS:** I've realized that this problem occurs at Chrome but not at Internet Explorer.

Comment: Please show us the XML input and the `value` attribute value you have in the XML input.

Comment: Response from server is: `TECHNO A.&amp;amp;amp;#x15E;.`

Answer (score 0):

&# and ; are html parser escapes for hexadecimal character. So what you need to do is to strip off them and pass the remaining '15E' value into this (for example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="myId">
yo oyyoyoyooy &amp;amp;amp;#xAA;suuupspuspupsu
  ssdosudoisduoisudoiud
  &amp;amp;#xFE;
</div>


<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
  // Node to use as root
    document.getElementById('myId'),

    // Only consider nodes that are text nodes (nodeType 3)
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,

    // Object containing the function to use for the acceptNode method
    // of the NodeFilter
      { acceptNode: function(node) {
        // Logic to determine whether to accept, reject or skip node
        // In this case, only accept nodes that have content
        // other than whitespace
        if ( /&.*?#x[^;]+;/ig.test(node.data) ) {
          return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        }
      }
    },
    false
  );

  // Show the content of every non-empty text node that is a child of root
  var node;

  while ((node = nodeIterator.nextNode())) {
    node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/&.*?#x([^;]+);/ig, function(match, p1) {
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(p1, 16))
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know what will come from server. Any value can be returned .

Comment: @kamaci I updated the answer check it out, generally it collects all the text nodes under a specific pattern of &...#x....; and catches whatever between #x and ; and replaces them, this will get all your cases covered because all the data coming from server is escaped in similiar manner. Hope it helps.